# User gender manually passing through User property is not showing in Firebase Analytics DebugView

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

### User gender manually passing through User property is not showing in Firebase Analytics DebugView

I passed application's user's gender in firebase analytics using User Property. I am passing property value like,

```
 mFirebaseAnalytics?.setUserProperty("app_user_gender", "male")
```

In logcat, it's showing like,

`D/FA: Setting user property (FE): app_user_gender, male`

that means Firebase SDK sending this User property. but in DebugView it's not showing like other properties showing.

[image]

I know that Gender automatically tracked by Firebase but i want exact gender value for Application's user.

**I have another Question like,**

How can I analyse Event with it's Property values
for example, i have one event like `login_with` which has `login_using` property and i am passing `phone` and `email` as value. So i want to know that, How many users login with `email`? Can anybody please tell me that how can i check this thing in Firebase Analytics Dashboard?

Comment: So you're saying you have other user properties that are showing up in debug view? If you click on an event, that's where you should see the user properties associated with the event.

Comment: @JenPerson i am unable to see app_user_gender property in debug view.

Comment: @SanjayPrajapati Even I am facing the same issue. Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking in the wrong card. All the user properties are shown and displayed under the Current User Properties table that shows the latest state of the set of User Properties for the currently selected development device.

Check debug events pertaining to [top events and current user properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#top_events_and_current_user_properties) for details.